# Code Behind file event handler with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, event-handling

I have a dropdownlist that displays "`Select`", I want to insert an event handler in my code behind file using c#. So that when "`Select`" is selected in the dropdownlist it will display a warning message on the webpage.

Curretnly I have:

> ```
>    protected void UpdateEmployeeBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         if (DropDownListEmployee.SelectedValue == "Select")
>         {
>             Response.Write("warning");
>             return false;
>         }
>  update code...
> }
> ```

I get an error/warning message for the return statement: "`returns void`, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression".

Comment: Why are you trying to return false from the event handler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 return false;
```

Your event handler is declared as void - you cannot return a `bool`. Just do `return;`

Comment: I have an html tag: <h1 id="warning"></h1> any idea how I would be able to send the warning message from the Response.Write inbetween the h1 tags? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Nick, that should be asked as another question.  It's not related to this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return values from a `void` method.  Change your statement to just `return;`